# Overhead of const modifier for built-in types in C++

Tags: c++, constants, overhead

I prefer to add `const` modifier to all built-in arguments in functions I write. E.g.:

```
void foo(const int arg1, const double arg2);
```

is better for me than:

```
void foo(int arg1, double arg2);
```

After code review I was told that `const` modifier brings an overhead when it is applied for integer and built-in types. Is that true and why?

Thanks,

Comment: It brings an overhead of 5 characters, `c`, `o`, `n`, `s` and `t`, I'll guess.

Comment: It's time to bring your CV up-to-date and look for a job where you can work with people that have a clue

Comment: no, it's a horrible 6! there's also a space

Comment: it has no overheads I agree..but for all all built-in types like `int` `char` `double` I prefer passing by value than as a const-reference. BTW, you are missing const-reference or is that intentional?

Comment: @Asha Who said anything about references?

Comment: @UweKeim 6 characters, since you need an additional space as a separator:-).

Comment: @Asha: I don't think anyone has mentioned references...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Then why hvae const qualifier there? any way we are passing by value, let the function modify that value if it intends to.

Comment: @Asha The const is purely for the benefit of the programmer, especially the maintenance programmer. Knowing that the value of a variable cannot change makes it easier for the human reader to analyse and reason about the function's behaviour.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's not without value, but honestly, if the human reader needs the additional information (or benefits significantly from it), isn't the function a little too complicated?

Comment: @JamesKanze: The first thing I do when refactoring those *a-little-too-complicated* functions is to `const` as many local vars as possible, then I can put them (the variables) out of my mind. Not all code you are exposed to out in the wild is as you'd prefer it to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has no more overhead than a `typedef` does. Your coworker is wrong.

If you want to convince him, print out the disassembly of both variants, and show your coworker that *they're the same*.

However, adding the `const` qualifier to primitive types like this is utterly pointless and futile. They're copied anyway, and there's no harm in modifying them. There's nothing to be gained by making them const.

Comment: It's not necessarily pointless (assuming we're talking about the function definition rather than the prototype).

Comment: Why not? What errors does it protect against? What is to be gained by making a copy of an `int` const?

Comment: The same as making any other local variable `const` (protects you from yourself, documents intent, etc.).

Comment: I don't quite see how. The intent is that a copy of the `int` is created. There's nothing in the callers intent that disallows or discourages the callee from modifying that copy. It may even be useful.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that it documents anything in the caller-callee interface.  But it may help the author/editor of the function implementation itself.

Comment: @Oli: it's pointless (in jalf's sense) putting the `const` in a non-defining declaration of the function, as the questioner has done. The pointfulness you describe concerns putting the `const` in a definition of the function, but the question doesn't show any definitions. There may also be some value in having the declaration and the definition byte-wise identical, rather than just equivalent, in which case you could shove it in the declaration too and say that doing so isn't pointless.

Answer (score 4):

There's no overhead with `const`, I guess your coworkers are just confused with the use as it is (unfortunately) not so common. Personally I prefer to `const` as many local variables as possible since it increases readability.

Of course it's always easy to disprove, take the following program and compile with assembly output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo1(int a, double b)
{
  printf("Not const %d, %g\n", a, b);
}

void foo2(const int a, const double b)
{
  printf("Const %d, %g\n", a, b);
}


int main()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    foo1(i, 5.5 * i);
    foo2(i, 12.8 * i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The assembly code generated for those functions is exactly the same (using VS2010 release-build):

For `foo1` (without `const`-specifiers):

```
; 4    : {

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp

; 5    :    printf("Not const %d, %g\n", a, b);

fld     QWORD PTR _b$[ebp]
sub     esp, 8
fstp    QWORD PTR [esp]
push    eax
push    OFFSET ??_C@_0BC@FACFPKBC@Not?5const?5?$CFd?0?5?$CFg?6?$AA@
call    DWORD PTR __imp__printf
add     esp, 16                 ; 00000010H

; 6    : }
```

For `foo2` (with `const`-specifiers):

```
; 9    : {

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp

; 10   :    printf("Const %d, %g\n", a, b);

fld     QWORD PTR _b$[ebp]
sub     esp, 8
fstp    QWORD PTR [esp]
push    eax
push    OFFSET ??_C@_0O@LOLEPDHC@Const?5?$CFd?0?5?$CFg?6?$AA@
call    DWORD PTR __imp__printf
add     esp, 16                 ; 00000010H

; 11   : }
```

Comment: How can it catch a `const` violation then?

Answer (score 3):

That is not true.

Independent of that, you should not put `const` into the function *declaration*, since it is an implementation detail: it only qualifies the *local* variable in the function scope. So you can write it like this:

```
double foo(unsigned int a, double b);  // declaration

double foo(unsigned int const a, double b)  // implementation
{
    b *= a;
    return bar(b);   // silly example
}
```

Comment: Which could cause confusion because the declaration and the definition differ visually.  I don't use `const` here for that reason, but I can certainly understand his position; whether the advantages of the `const` outweigh the possible confusion due to the different appearance is really a very subjective judgement call.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true.<sup>1</sup>

Or, more precisely, I can't think of a reason why it could be true.  All `const` does is force the compiler to check that you're not changing the value of the variable; but that's a compile-time check.

---

<sub>1. Assuming we're using the traditional definition of "overhead" that relates to runtime performance or compiled code size.</sub>

Comment: He doesn't state which kind of "overhead" he refers to. I can think of program speed, program size, compilation speed or code readability.

Comment: @UweKeim: That's true.  But until it's qualified further, I'm going to assume runtime overhead (although I've now made that explicit in my answer, thanks!).

Comment: In fact, because his arguments become const objects, there's a distinct possibility that the compiler can optimize more with the `const`.  (In practice, I expect that with optimization active, most compilers will detect that the objects aren't modified, with or without the const.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: which optimization would be enabled by this?

Comment: @jalf The compiler knows that a `const` object doesn't change value once it has been initialized.  In practice, most compilers will recognize that this is the case anyway, but if you pass the argument by reference or by pointer to another function, the compiler cannot be sure that that function doesn't cast away const and modify the value unless the object itself is actually const.

Comment: @JamesKanze: we're talking about an `int` and a `double` here, which are passed by copy *anyway*, so in the function call, no optimization will take place. Inside the function, the compiler's dataflow analysis is much better able to determine what gets modified and what doesn't (and, again, because these are primitive types, it doesn't really matter whether they get modified)

Comment: @jalf There are things that the compiler cannot see, for example if the value is passed by reference or by pointer to an external function: if the object is not const, the compiler must assume that it could be modified by the function (by casting away const); if the object itself is const, the compiler can consider that it won't be modified, since trying to modify it would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> After code review I was told that const modifier brings an overhead when it is applied for integer and built-in types. Is that true and why?

Who you gave your code to review it? A junior programmer?

The above is not true. Quite the contrary. Using const might apply some optimization.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not true.

I think you/they confused const with passing by reference.

Answer (score 1):

What type of overhead do you mean? 
Overhead for compiled binary or overhead of compiler? I'm sure that compiled binary is identicall for the first and the second code samples you've added. For compiler - maybe. Const adds additional conditional, that must be checked in compile-time.

Comment: Systematic use of `const` increases the file size.  With very simple languages and no optimization, the time to read the file could be a significant, or even a predominant, part of compile time.  C++ doesn't qualify as a "very simple language", however, and even without optimization, things like template type deduction are going to outweigh the time it takes to simply read the file.

Answer (score 1):

It can bring overhead, if it forces you to create an additional local variable.

Without const

```
void foo(const int arg1, double arg2)
{
    if (arg1 == 1)
        arg2 += 5.0;

    // use arg2
}
```

With const

```
void foo(const int arg1, const double arg2)
{
    double arg2Copy;
    if (arg1 == 1)
        arg2Copy = arg2 + 5.0;
    else
        arg2Copy = arg2;

    // use arg2Copy
}
```

But this really depends on the compiler. If you're concerned about the overhead, you should compare the generated code.

Comment: Any sane compiler should optimise these to be identical.

Comment: Why do you consider that to be "overhead"? Declaring an extra variable won't affect the generated code